# logging issues with python flask

Tags: python, logging, flask

I am trying to configure my flask app using the dictConfig and configuring sqlalchemy logging, etc.

I have a yaml file as below

```
version: 1

root:
  handlers: [console]
  level: INFO


loggers:
  sqlalchemy.engine:
    level: WARN
    propagate: false
    handlers: []
  clportal:
    level: INFO
    handlers: [console]
    propagate: false

handlers:
  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    formatter: standard
    level: INFO
    stream: ext://sys.stdout

formatters:
  standard:
    format: '%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(name)-10s: %(message)s'
```

Which I log by doing the following:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask('clportal')
    configure_logging()
    app.logger.info('from app.logger')
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
    app.secret_key = app.config["SECRET_KEY"]
    finjector = FlaskInjector(app=app, modules=[ConfigurationModule(app)])
    app.injector = finjector
    #app.logger.setLevel(app.config['LOG_LEVEL'])
    # add stdout handler (used for docker etc)
    #stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    # stdout_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(message)s'))
    #app.logger.addHandler(stdout_handler)
    #app.logger.info('Set up correctly now?')
    return app


def configure_logging():
    logging.config.dictConfig(yaml.load(open(os.path.join(APP_PATH, 'logconfig.yml'), 'r')))
```

Logging via the app.logger.info, will only work if I comment out those llines in the create_app function.

I'd love to be able to configure all my logging via the yaml file.  Any ideas why this doesnt work?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've tried doing it as the first step via http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/logging/ but that just won't work for me.

Instead I've found to do the following.  Initiate the default loggers by accessing app.logger with a statement, then run the config logging using the yaml file and all will be good.  If I did the config via yaml before the app is created, as specified in the help, it won't override the default handlers.

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask('clportal')
    app.logger.info('initing app.logger')
    logging.config.dictConfig(yaml.load(open(os.path.join(APP_PATH, 'logconfig.yml'), 'r')))
    app.logger.info('app logger has now been reset')
    app.config.from_pyfile(os.path.join(APP_PATH, 'config.py'))
    app.secret_key = app.config["SECRET_KEY"]
    finjector = FlaskInjector(app=app, modules=[ConfigurationModule(app)])
    app.injector = finjector
    return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_app().run()
```

and my working yaml

```
version: 1
disable_existing_loggers: true
root:
  handlers: [console]
  level: INFO


loggers:
  sqlalchemy.engine:
    level: WARN
    propagate: false
    handlers: []
  clportal:
    level: INFO
    handlers: [console]
    propagate: false

handlers:
  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    formatter: standard
    level: INFO
    stream: ext://sys.stdout

formatters:
  standard:
    format: '%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(name)-10s: %(message)s'
```

Answer (score -2):

This is because the name of `app.logger` is not really `"app.logger"`. If you try to print `app.logger.name`, you will find its real name. And you should use this name in `logconfig.yml` such as:

```
loggers:
  sqlalchemy.engine:
    level: WARN
    propagate: false
    handlers: []
  real_name:
    level: INFO
    handlers: [console]
    propagate: false
```

Or you can use a custom logger to replace default logger:

```
# python scirpt
logger = logging.getLogger("what_ever_you_want")
app.logger = logger

# logconfig.yml
loggers:
  sqlalchemy.engine:
    level: WARN
    propagate: false
    handlers: []
  what_ever_you_want:
    level: INFO
    handlers: [console]
    propagate: false
```

Comment: Thanks @sraw I've set the name correctly, but still no dice.  Added a screenshot above to see what is actually there.  Seems to have been somehow overwritten?

Comment: @Cameron So I think you have already solve this problem? Do you mind accept my answer?